# Test production specific code with rspec - Sinatra

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, sinatra

I have this code to configure logging for production and test/development environments:

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base
  configure :development, :test do
    enable :logging
    file = File.new("#{settings.root}/../../log/#{settings.environment}.log", 'a+')
    file.sync = true
    use Rack::CommonLogger, file
  end


  configure :production do
    enable :logging
    log_file = File.new("#{settings.root}/../../log/#{settings.environment}.log", 'a+')

    STDOUT.reopen(log_file)
    STDERR.reopen(log_file)

    STDOUT.sync = true
    STDERR.sync = true
  end
end
```

The issue being simplecov is stating I'm not testing the production block as I'm setting my environment to be 'test' within my spec_helper file.

Is there a way to test both 'test' and 'production' code with rspec?

Answer (score 0):

You could break out the code in the body of the `configure` block into one or methods that take the environment value as an argument, then write a separate test for those methods. However, I would advise against complicating the code if the only goal is to get to 100% coverage.